# laravel installation error with composer

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I have faced the following problem during the installation of laravel php framework.
following errors appeared when I run the command `composer global require "laravel/ installer"`.

NB: I already have installed xampp, composer and add these to environment variable. 
the following picture will clear the problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ovj4.png)

Comment: Your internet connection seems to not be working on that machine. Maybe try again.

Comment: tried again but there's no good. i also have a working net connection

Comment: I am not sure if this matters, but you have space between the `/` and the package name. Can you try `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: gives the same result @Latheesan

Comment: Have you tried creating the laravel project without the installer like this: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-app-name`

Comment: Are you using git or the normal command prompt?

Comment: yes, i tried that and then i realize that i haven't install laravel yet. I have tried probably this command composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp @Latheesan

Comment: normal command prompt @WosleyAlarico

Comment: try to run it using git

Comment: gives the same result https://ibb.co/gRVEY8 @WosleyAlarico

Comment: @sourav can you try any of the 2 commands in other PC ? I think you have a firewall of something like that

Comment: how i can resolve the problem in my pc @matiaslauriti

Comment: @sourav I don't know, did it work in other pc ?

Comment: Probably it is permissions problem on Windows. Try to do installation procedure, under directory created in your user `Documents` dir on Windows. And don't use global in composer, cause your composer is not installed to work this way...

Comment: i didn't try it in other pc which has ubuntu os and i will not carry that pc with me. please give some solution to resolve the problem for this machine @matiaslauriti

Comment: i have tried to install in both two directories 1. C:\xampp\htdocs
2. C:\Users\_po>(default directory) @Bart

Comment: @sourav but I  mean `global` directive for composer... Ok lets start new CMD with admin rights and then execute your installs with composer... Do you get any errors then?

Comment: Yes @Bart got the same problem by trying run as administrator

Comment: @sourav strange. I assume your result matches the pic posted earlier with errors and you get exactly the same errors this time. Then disable (shortly,only to check this) all antivirus/malware you have on your system. And run it all again...To verify that this software is not interfering...

Comment: BTW @sourav follow laravel docs on installing homestead https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead. You will get much more flexible environment and close to production. Using LAMP or XAMPP should be no go, for your Laravel development on Windows...

Comment: please check the picture @Bart https://ibb.co/g76fqo

Comment: @sourav sad to see that... I really believe the problem is in your Windows permissions...

Comment: @sourav but please reconsider using homestead. Definitely you will spend some time on installing and familiarizing with it. But once, it is done, you will have, the best possible testing environment for your app, which sticks to CI/CD conventions...

Comment: i will try using homestead @Bart and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used php version 5.6 and tried to install laravel having this version. 
Later I have uninstalled xampp and install the latest version of xampp and things are working now